# Issue with integration test for spring boot with couchdb

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers, spring-data-couchbase

I'm pretty new to couchbase but fair experienced with spring boot. I have the following:

Repository:

```java
import entity.Building;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.Collection;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository;

@Collection("buildings")
public interface BuildingRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Building, String> {
    
}
```

Building:

```java
@Document
public class Building {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    private String id;

    @Field
    @NotNull
    private String erf;
    
    @Field
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    
    @Field
    @NotNull
    private Address address;

    @CreatedBy
    private String creator;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModification;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    
    @Version
    private long version;
}
```

Test case:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class RetrieveBuildingTest {
    @Container
    private static final CouchbaseContainer COUCHBASE = new CouchbaseContainer(
            DockerImageName.parse("couchbase/server:7.1.2")).withBucket(new BucketDefinition("buildings").withPrimaryIndex(true));

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void testLifecycleForBuildings() throws Exception {
        final ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("payloads/successful-create-building.json");
        final String payload = Files.readString(Path.of(resource.getURI()));

        // save
        mvc.perform(post("/building")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(payload))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is("Knightsbridge Mansion")));
        
        // retrieval all
        
        mvc.perform(get("/building"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.totalElements", is(1)));
        
        // retrieve specific building by id
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    public static void register(final DynamicPropertyRegistry register) {
        register.add("spring.couchbase.connection-string", COUCHBASE::getConnectionString);
        register.add("spring.couchbase.username", COUCHBASE::getUsername);
        register.add("spring.couchbase.password", COUCHBASE::getPassword);
    }
```

I see in some examples there is **AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration** but I'd think that the properties would have set this up. I've also set the following properties in `application.properties`:

```
spring.data.couchbase.bucket-name=buildings
spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.connect=30
spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.key-value-durable=30
```

Errors from the log:

```
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:581)
Caused by: com.couchbase.client.core.error.AmbiguousTimeoutException: InsertRequest, Reason: TIMEOUT {"cancelled":true,"completed":true,"coreId":"0xf0d3d25700000001","idempotent":false,"lastChannelId":"F0D3D25700000001/0000000058CD068A","lastDispatchedFrom":"127.0.0.1:38858","lastDispatchedTo":"localhost:49158","reason":"TIMEOUT","requestId":5,"requestType":"InsertRequest","retried":14,"retryReasons":["COLLECTION_MAP_REFRESH_IN_PROGRESS"],"service":{"bucket":"buildings","collection":"buildings","documentId":"54b991d2-fa8b-41eb-9b1e-d5519914e964","opaque":"0x15","scope":"_default","type":"kv","vbucket":233},"timeoutMs":2500,"timings":{"encodingMicros":5785,"totalMicros":2512314}}
    at com.couchbase.client.core.msg.BaseRequest.cancel(BaseRequest.java:184)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.msg.Request.cancel(Request.java:70)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.Timer.lambda$register$2(Timer.java:157)
```

Answer (score 0):

`spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.connect` and `spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.key-value-durable` are missing the unit. Default values are 10 seconds. If not specified then it will convert to milis and that's how the timeout is produced. In order to fix it set `30s`.

See more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.conversion.durations)

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase tried 14 times to refresh the collection map in order to process the insert, but never succeeded. Likely because the cluster or bucket is not yet ready.  Use the Java SDKs waitUntilReady() to wait until the bucket is ready to be used before trying to use it.

"retried":14,"retryReasons":["COLLECTION_MAP_REFRESH_IN_PROGRESS"]